# Can I say there would be only 2 groups with such features in this data and prove it using cluster analysis?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, clustering

I assume that there would be two groups that will emerge within the data with my assumed features. I run cluster analysis and best number of cluster (elbow, dendrogram, etc.) shows it will be 2 and with my assumed features. Does this constitute a legitimate statistical hypothesis test?

Comment: What do you mean by "features"? I think I know what you mean, but...

Comment: Say I use two variables: knowledge and belief. I assume that the data will include two clusters: knowledge high-belief low and knowledge low-belief high. This is my hypothesis and I find that hierarchical cluster analysis shows 2-cluster solution seems best. So it confirms my hypothesis. Just wondered whether I can use cluster analysis to test such hypothesis?

Comment: If you really have two variables, cluster analysis is redundant. Draw a scatter plot and see if there are just two groups. Your wording jumps from proving to testing, so making your stance unclear. If you tell a technique to find 2 clusters that's what it will do. Saying whether 1 or 3 or 4 or ... clusters would be better addresses "are there 2 clusters rather than some other number?", but does not so well address whether clustering is the right idea. Further, a hypothesis test, strict sense, is tied up with an idea that there's uncertainty, e.g. about sampling. How does that enter here?

Comment: In addition, I assume that other cluster possibilities (knowledgehigh-beliefhigh or knowledge low-belieflow) are impossible.